# if we change the value of the the string then a new object will be created . So how can we access the previous string object

Tags: java, string

As we know, strings are immutable in nature.
If we want to change the value of the string, then a new address will be allocated inside the string pool of the heap area. But finally, we are changing the value of the string. So how can we access the previous string value it if we want to?

```java
String str = " Anupam ";
System.out.println(str.hashCode());
System.out.println(str);
str = "Anand";
System.out.println(str.hashCode());
System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: initializing it back to the original value will give you the previous string object

Comment: Both the title and the second sentence are false. Quesiton is founded on false premisses.

Answer (score 0):

If this is in **Java** then No, you cant access the previous value until you had made a copy of the previous `str`.

*You can use setters and implement a mechanism to keep the old value(s)*

```
private String str;
private String previous;

setStr(String s)
{
    previous = str;
    str = s;
}
```

You can look below thread to know some ways:

[Can you get the previous value of a variable in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610976/can-you-get-the-previous-value-of-a-variable-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

The `String.hashcode()` is not same as `Object.hashcode()` since `String` class overrides this method to this value.
`s[0]*31^(n - 1) + s[1]*31^(n - 2) + ... + s[n - 1]`
(Reference : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_hashcode.htm )

To find the hashcode from `Object.hashcode()`, use `System.identityHashCode(Object x)`

And even the `Object.hashcode()` is not equal to the memory address of the object. (Hashcode is generated 'from' memory address, but it is not equal.)

Quote from https://coderanch.com/t/476276/java/Object-based-hashcode Henry Wong's Answer,

> The identity hashcode is *not* the location/address of the object. It may have been originally generated using the address. But even if you can calculate the address from the identity hashcode, objects are moved around by the garbage collector (while the identity hashcode doesn't change). If there is a relationship between the memory address and the identity hashcode of the object, it won't remain for very long.

So you could not get the memory address, and the previous value from the memory address either.

Comment: @Andy Please accept the answer if you satisfied about it.